# How to filer Kendo grid with respect to column filter and searchbox text value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid and I already appy a column filter and I need to filter this result with a text box value I  tried like

```
var sText = $("#searchBox").val();
                if (sText.length > 0) {
                var filterChild = [];
                var filtOut = [];
                var ds = $('#homeGridCustomer').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
                var curr_filters = ds.filter();
                filterChild.push({ field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: sText });
                filterChild.push({ field: "City", operator: "contains", value: sText });
                filterChild.push({ field: "CustomerNo", operator: "contains", value: sText });
                var filtParent = { filters: filterChild, logic: "or" };
                if (curr_filters != undefined) {
                    filtOut.push(curr_filters);
                }
                filtOut.push(filtParent);
                ds.filter({ filters: filtOut, logic: "and" });
```

but it didn't getting the filtered output, nothing is showing. can anyone help ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to apply multiple search filters to multiple columns in the `dataSource` based on the same input value and maintain the existing filters already applied (with the ability to clear the filters when nothing is entered in the search area), try using:

```
var ds = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;        

var sText = $("#nameOfYourInput").val();
var filterToApply = ds.filter();
if(!filterToApply) {
  // if not, setup new filter
  filterToApply = {
     logic: "and", // use OR here if you want to search for a value in either column instead of all columns
     filters: []
  }
}

var applyFilters = false;
// check to see if `sText` contains value before filtering (as filter will apply like `Name`/`City`/`CustomerNo` `contains` `null`/`undefined` otherwise)
if(sText) {
  applyFilters = true;
  filterToApply.filters.push({field: "foo", operator: "contains", value: sText});
  filterToApply.filters.push({field: "bar", operator: "contains", value: sText});    
}
if(applyFilters) {
  ds.filter([filterToApply]);
}
else {
  ds.filter([]);
}
```

I have attached a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/hupukobeji/1/edit?html,js,output) for you to play about with which defaults to overwriting existing grid filters based on the new input value, and have included commented out code which can be used to build on top of existing filters. Hopefully you can get what you need from this.